# Android how to get the color of LinearLayout "style="@android:style/ButtonBar""

Tags: android, colors, background, android-linearlayout

i want to get programmatically the background color of a LinearLayout with style 'ButtonBar'.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

I tried to use the getBackgroundColor of the LinearLayout, but did not find the method.

Does anyone has an idea ?
Greets

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonBar);

PaintDrawable d = (PaintDrawable)layout.getBackground();
Paint paint = d.getPaint();
int color = paint.getColor();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="#CCCC99">
```

Comment: Dont get the bar color just simply insert on the background color and its working :)